# Why won't the lower agitator on my washing machine spin?

Tags: repair, washing-machine

I have a Whirlpool top load washing machine. I recently replaced the dogs on the agitator which was very easy. The top agitator works like it is supposed to, but the bottom doesn't move. It's like it's locked down.

What would cause this? Do I have to replace it or can I save it?